# I want to get total amount monthly with filled gaps,i mean 0 for months having no transactions

Tags: mysql, database, group-by

I have made a table '`saving`' with columns `ac_no,Transaction_id` and `amount`.

Other table is just filled with random dates.

So far I have tried this query which i think is very close..

1) 
`select 
       sd.ac_no,year(sd.Transaction_date) as Transaction_year,month(sd.Transaction_date) as Transaction_month,
       sum(sd.amount) as Total
    from saving sd
    left join other dt
      on sd.Transaction_date = dt.Transaction_date
    where sd.ac_no = 11  and sd.Transaction_date between '2014-01-01' and '2014-12-31'
    group by year(sd.Transaction_date),month(sd.Transaction_date)`

---

and I am getting this result:

```
AccountNumber   Transaction_year    Transaction_month   Total
11                  2014                    3           5000
11                  2014                    7           1000
```

---

but I want result like this:

```
AccountNumber   Transaction_year    Transaction_month     Total
11                        2014               1                      0
11                        2014               2                      0
11                        2014           3                  5000
11                        2014               4                      0
11                        2014               5                      0
11                        2014               6                      0
11                        2014           7                  1000
```

Please help and thanx in advance..

Comment: You need a calendar table,use this procedure to create and then JOIN it with your results. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d6cd52/1

Comment: You don't *need* a calendar... but that is one way ;-) Consider handling issues of data display (including missing data) at the application level (assuming you have one)

Comment: @Mihai I have already tried the procedure but getting same results CREATE TABLE calendar (datefield DATE)
DELIMITER |
CREATE PROCEDURE fill_calendar(start_date DATE, end_date DATE)
BEGIN
  DECLARE crt_date DATE;
  SET crt_date=start_date;
  WHILE crt_date < end_date DO
    INSERT INTO calendar VALUES(crt_date);
    SET crt_date = ADDDATE(crt_date, INTERVAL 1 DAY);
  END WHILE;
END |
DELIMITER ;
CALL fill_calendar('2014-01-01', '2014-12-31');